# ASP.NET MVC - Return View with Custom Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My application has a custom route that looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "ProjectDocument",
  url: "Project/{projectid}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Document", action = "Index", projectid = 0, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Basically, there are multiple projects and each project can have documents.  The documents may have the same id so I need the combination of projectid and documentid to get the correct document.

I've created an  Edit view ("/Project/101/Document/Edit/78"). When the user posts the form, I first check the ModelState in my "Document" controller.  If that fails, I want to return the model/modelstate to the view to show the errors.  With normal routing, I would just use

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
return View(model);
}
```

but this doesn't work with the custom route because it returns "Document/Edit/78" (without the custom routing).

Can someone point me in the right direction for how I would return the full custom route on that error?

Thanks

UPDATED PER REQUEST

In my Documents Controller

GET

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int projectid, int id)
{
...
```

POST

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(ProjectDocument projectdocument)
{
...
```

Comment: What are the signatures of your controller GET and POST methods for the `Edit()` method?

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(ProjectDocument projectdocument)

Comment: Please edit the question (not in comments), and include the signature for the GET as well

Comment: Cannot repeat that behavior at all - it returns the same url as the the original. There is something else in your code cause the issue

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'returns the same url as the original'.  Does it return "/Project/101/Document/Edit/78" for you?

Comment: Yes, and that is the standard behavior. Something else in your code is causing a different url to be displayed in the address bar when you return the view.

Comment: figured it out :-| . thanks @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had my new route *below* the Default route in my RouteConfig.cs file.  Thanks to Stephen for pushing me to look a bit further into other parts of my code.